# Set default "Link CSS Class" in add media admin editor

Tags: uploads, media, visual-editor, wp-editor, images

I want to set the default link css class to all those images which are added to admin editor. I have found the way to add default image class with this action:

```
function add_image_class($class){
    $class .= ' img-frame';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

but couldn't find the way to do the same with "Link CSS Class"

[image: Link CSS Class]

Comment: `get_link_tag_class` isn't a core WordPress filter. Where did you get it?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question, it should be get_image_tag_class.
I was able to set the image class with this filter and now i'm looking for similar solution with "link CSS Class" option

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter here like so:

```
function custom_class( $attr ) {    
    $attr['class'] = 'custom-class';
    return $attr;
});
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'custom_class' );
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work. Maybe this will work on featured images, but not the images which are uploaded in editor